Cartesian product space is complete in the uniform metric
I am reading the Theorem 43.5 of Munkres:
If the space $Y$ is complete in the metric $d$, then the space $Y^J$ is complete in the uniform metric $\bar{\rho}$ corresponding to $d$.
The question concerns the statement in the proof "letting $m$ become arbitrarily large, we see that $\bar{d}(f_n(\alpha),f(\alpha)) \leq \epsilon/2$". Does $m$ exist?
Here is my thought:
Suppose that $n$ and $\alpha$ are fixed. Since $\{f_n(\alpha)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in complete metric space $(Y,\bar{d})$,
there exists $M$ such that whenever $m\geq M$, $\bar{d}(f_m(\alpha),f(\alpha))<\epsilon/3$.
Therefore, $\bar{d}(f_n(\alpha),f(\alpha))\leq \bar{d}(f_n(\alpha),f_m(\alpha))+\bar{d}(f_m(\alpha),f(\alpha))< \epsilon/2+\epsilon/3<5\epsilon/6 $.
$\bar{\rho}$ is the supremum of $\bar{d}$ over $\alpha\in J$. Then $\bar{\rho}\leq 5\epsilon/6<\epsilon$.
However, in order to make this approach work, we should take $m\geq M_\alpha $ for each $\alpha \in J$.  It seems that such an $m$ may not exist, as we would need $m$ to satisfy conditions like $m\geq N, m \geq N+1,...$
Is this approach correct? If not, what is the right way to understand the proof? Any help would be appreciated.

$M$ does not depend on $\alpha$. $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in the uniform metric, not just  coordinate-wise Cauchy.
